# discord.js fetch user integrations

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js bot and I want to read user integrations from the user id. But I can't find it from the docs and I don't know how to do it. Since I can see the integrations when I log in, I think that it would be available with discod.js, too. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think there's a way, but somebody else may know how

Comment: Do you mean guild/server *integrations*, i.e. YouTube/Twitch streamers adding a role for their subscribers, or user *connections*, i.e. any user connecting their YouTube, Spotify, Xbox etc. accounts? For the former integrations, you can use [Guild#fetchIntegrations](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchIntegrations). For the latter connections, you need the `connections` OAuth 2 scope (see [API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user-connections)), and Discord.js does not support OAuth 2.

Comment: I meant the user connection. Bad news️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't fetch user connections without using Oauth2, unfortunately.